# I am trying to use redux-infinite-scroll for scrolling effect but endpoint call is happening infinitely

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux-infinite-scroll for scrolling effect but once action gets dispatched action creator gets executed infinitely. I am giving my code as well.
Thanks

Here is my action creator -

```
export function search_terms(newpricerange,newmaketype,newbodytype) {
    const terms={
       make_id: newmaketype?  newmaketype:localStorage.getItem("newselectedmake"),
       bodytype_id: newbodytype?
       newbodytype:localStorage.getItem("newselectedbodytype"),
       min_exshowroomprice: newpricerange?newpricerange[0]:localStorage.getItem("newselectedminprice"),
       max_exshowroomprice: newpricerange?newpricerange[1]:localStorage.getItem("newselectedmaxprice"),
       status_id: 3
      };
    return function(dispatch){
        return axios({
            url:`${base_url3}`,
            headers:{
            'Authorization':'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem("access_token")
            },
            params: terms,
            method:'get'
        })
       .then(
            function(response){
                let vehicle_list = {
                    type: VEHICLE_LIST,
                    payload: response
                };
                return dispatch(vehicle_list);
            });
         };
      }
```

and here is my `_loadMore` function -

```
_loadMore() {
    this.props.dispatch(search_terms());
}
```

this is how i am using infinitescroll -

```
<InfiniteScroll
    items={this._renderMessages()}
    loadMore={this._loadMore.bind(this)}
    threshold={1}
    containerHeight={300}
    showLoader={true}
/>
```

here I am mapping through all data -

```
_renderMessages() {
    let j=1;
    if(this.props.vehicle_list && this.props.fetchlist && this.props.engine_list && this.props.exterior_sizes && this.props.infotainment){
        return __.uniqBy(this.props.vehicle_list.data.data,'model_id.id').map((vehicle) => {
            result = __.filter(this.props.fetchlist.data.data, function(o) {  if(o.media_section_id.media_type_id.id==1){return vehicle.model_id.id === o.model_id.id; } });
            let enginetype = __.filter(this.props.engine_list.data.data, function(o) { return vehicle.id === o.vehicle_id.id;  });
            let exterior_sizes = __.filter(this.props.exterior_sizes.data.data, function(o) { return vehicle.id === o.vehicle_id.id; });
            let infotainment = __.filter(this.props.infotainment.data.data, function(o) { return vehicle.id === o.vehicle_id.id;  });
            let mediaarr = __.sampleSize(result, 3);
            if (mediaarr.length>0) {
                return(
                <ResultVechicle
                    vehicle={vehicle}
                    result={result}
                    enginetype={enginetype}
                    exterior_sizes={exterior_sizes}
                    infotainment={infotainment}
                    mediaarr={mediaarr}
                    key={vehicle.id}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    dropdownid={j++}
                />);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what i am doing wrong i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Is this based on https://github.com/RealScout/redux-infinite-scroll ?

Comment: yes same package i am using.

Comment: how can i use this